# Crystal Report : "File is too large for attachment" Error

Tags: crystal-reports, report, business-objects, crystal-reports-server

I am new for crystal report server. Here I'm explaining error details.

I'm using SAP Business Objects CMC for report generation for my application. Below is the version details in image.

[image]

When I try to generate report file with more than 1MB of file size it is throwing below error.

```
Error 

The viewer could not process an event. 1c84865dce535c5.pdf File is too large for attachment. [] ---- Error code:0 [CRWEB00000119]
```

So, I went to following location to check the `maximumUploadFileSize`.

```
1. C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\webapps\dswsbobje\WEB-INF\classes\dsws.properties

2. C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\warfiles\webapps\dswsbobje\WEB-INF\classes\dsws.properties

3. C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\pjs\container\work\<ServerName>.WebApplicationContainerServer\businessobjects\dswsbobje\WEB-INF\classes\dsws.properties
```

> #Security measure to limit total upload file size
>
> maximumUploadFileSize = 10485760

It is setted to `10485760 (10 MB)`, As per my understanding this is default size from this [Reference Document](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4_wssdk_admin_en.pdf).

So, if it is supporting upto 10 MB why it is throwing error when report file exceed `1MB`?

And I tried to increase the size by multiple's of `10`, meaning `104857600 (100 MB)` in all this files, and restarted the server. But with out success, after restarting the server the modified value in third file is again setting to old value `(10485760)`. Please help me in this.

Is there any way to increase `maximumUploadFileSize` through administrator console?

Please drop your comments, if you have any questions/doubts regarding this.

Comment: What is the method that causes this error?

Comment: The report is generating from application, when it has less record (<1MB of report file size) it is working fine, but if it exceeds more than that it is throwing "File is too large for attachment"  error.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco:  thanks for your valuable time to gone through this question, I have resolved this issue. Please check below my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by following steps.

Actually this issue is related to number of records which are trying to generate as report in crystal report server. The default record data size limit is `20,000`. By changing the limit into `0 (for Unlimited)` we can able to resolve this issue.

**Follow below steps to do this setting changes:**

> 1. Log onto the CMC
> 2. Go to `Servers` in the drop-down menu
> 3. Expand `Service Categories`
> 4. Select `Crystal Reports Services`
> 5. In the right window will be listed the currently running services, find `CrystalReports2013ProcessingServer` under `Description`.
> 6. Double click on that, it will redirect to `Properties` page.
> 7. Set the value `0` for `"Database Records Read When Previewing or Refreshing (0 for unlimited)"`.
> 8. Click `Save & Close`.
> 9. Restart `CrystalReports2013ProcessingServer`.

Now try to generate the large data pdf file, it should work fine.

Comment: Seems dangerous to allow 0 Unlimited. If you have a PDF with 2 million rows, that could allow the Crystal Server to run out of memory as it is processing and generating the PDF.

Comment: Seriously I've not thought about that, In that case i think we should predict the maximum records for the report pragmatically and proceed further. But is it possible to set Crystal server configuration at runtime? or by any external api or technology?