# Crystal report : File is too large for attachment. Error code:0 [CRWEB00000119]

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server, crystal-reports-2011

I am completely noob to crystal report , I have been getting this error , when I invoke a crystal report.

The viewer could not process an event. 69699249b79df46.pdf File is too large for attachment. [] ---- Error code:0 [CRWEB00000119]

[image]

I have already viewed a similar issue (link below) and its resolution , which does not resolves my issue.

[Crystal Report : "File is too large for attachment" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671433/crystal-report-file-is-too-large-for-attachment-error)

Please help how do I resolve my issue.

Comment: This might help: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1536448 - what is the row count if you run the SQL directly? Are you running report from CMC? Is the final report format PDF, RPT, etc? Are there any images, videos, etc with the report?

Comment: i found the issue the issue was occurring as the query was failing due to incorrect data in the DB.